# Prestashop module hook to product pages

Tags: php, hook, prestashop

I am developing a module in prestashop. The module has been hooked into left column and right column and its working fine with that. Now I want to show the module output in product footer page. So for that can someone tell me how to hook my module to the product details page? Any help and suggestions will be really appreciable.

My code for leftColumn and rightColumn is like this

```
 function hookLeftColumn()
  {
    $defaultLanguage = (int)(Configuration::get('PS_LANG_DEFAULT'));
    global $cookie, $smarty;
    $value=array();
    $result="SELECT status,app_id from "._DB_PREFIX_."storeblocks";
    $value=Db::getInstance()->ExecuteS($result);
    $smarty->assign('array',$value);
    $smarty->assign('default',$defaultLanguage);
    return $this->display(__FILE__, 'stores.tpl');
  }

  function hookRightColumn()
  {
    return $this->hookLeftColumn();
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

For product page, there are several hooks available in PS.

You can use **displayLeftColumnProduct** hook, which hooks modules just below the image of the product.  You can also use **displayRightColumnProduct** which is for the right side section.

Another set of hooks is **displayProductTab** and **displayProductTabContent** , which are used for the tabs on the product page.

If these hooks don't help you, simply, then there are several other ways you can get your results. You can hook your module to any of that hooks which is more suitable for your needs, and then using css position and lft , top etc to move that hook to the required place.

If that is not a choice, then you will need to create your own hook and then using that hook on the product page. Please read this for creating your own hook

http://www.programmingtunes.com/creating-new-prestashop-hook/

Also for a complete list of the hooks in PS, please read this article in PS docs

http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS15/Hooks+in+PrestaShop+1.5

Let me know if you still need any other details.

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

notice:this answer is about prestashop 1.5 and also you can use it for prestashop 1.6 too.

if your means about `product details page` is the more info tab as i show in bellow image i can help you

[image: detail hook]

step1.you should instal two hook in install function in your module

```
   public function install() { 
    return   parent::install() &&
              $this->registerHook('displayProductTab')&&
               $this->registerHook('displayProductTabContent')
                 }
```

step2:you should use them and return the some html code
i want add a new tab i use.
notice:`id` is dynamic you change it but `class` is static should be use as the `selected`.
also `href` is linked to the content id(you see that in step 3)

```
   public function hookDisplayProductTab($params) {
      return '<li>
              <a id="myid" class="selected"  
               href="#linked">mytab</a>
                </li>'
               }
```

step3:if want when you click on mytab this show the it's content you add an other function.
notice:the href="#linked" at previous function is linked to the id="linked".

```
   public function hookDisplayProductTabContent($params){

      return <div id="linked" class="rte">
              <div class="product-overview-full">
               my contents
                </div>
                 </div>
              }
```

advanced:write your html or smarty in your .tpl and return theme weth this code

```
       return $this->display(__FILE__, 'mytpl.tpl') ;
```

best regards.

Comment: This example is useful when you want to have stored your files in module's folder:  `return $this->display(__FILE__,'views/hooks/mytpl.tpl');`

Comment: your welcome and thanks for your comment and thanks for your suggestion and you should know this tabs use in prestashop 1.5 and i don't see this tabs structure in prestashop 1.6. this article just use for history of prestashop  or use for freelancer maybe work with prestshop 1.5

Comment: Hello @moeinkh, I can see in 1.5 documentation that these hooks are available

Comment: I used this in prestashop 1.6.